# the population of rats surviving at a time t be governed by the differential equation $\frac{dp(t)}{{dt}}= \frac{1}{2}p(t) - 200.$ $p(t) = ?$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let the population of rabbits surviving at a time $t$ be governed by the differential equation $\frac{dp(t)}{{dt}}= \frac{1}{2}p(t) - 200.$ If $p(0) = 100$ , then $p(t)$ equals  $400 - 300 e^\frac{t}{2}$ .

Can anyone please check this question?

I think $p(0)$ can not be $100$. If $p(0) = 100$  , then $\frac{dp(t)}{{dt}}_{[ t = 0]}= \frac{1}{2}p(0) - 200 = -150.$  which is not possible. How $150$ rabbits will be reduced  at time $t=0$  , when the number of rabbits exist at $t=0$  is $100.$

Am I correct? Can anyone please help me?

**My attempt**:: $\frac{dp(t)}{dt}$ = $\frac{1}{2}p(t) - 200$

$$\frac{dp(t)}{\frac{1}{2} p(t) - 200} = dt$$

Now, taking integration both sides, we get

$$\int \frac{dp(t)}{\frac{1}{2} p(t) - 200} = \int dt$$

$\Rightarrow 2 \ln(\frac{{p(t)}}{2} - 200) = t + c, c$ is an arbitrary constant.\

$$\Rightarrow \frac{p(t)}{2} - 200 = ke^{\frac{t}{2}}$$

Using $p(0) = 100$  in above equation, we get $k = -150$

**If I was wrong , then how $K = e^{\frac{c}{2}} < 0$? Can anyone please explain?**

So, $p(t) = 400 - 300e^{\frac{t}{2}}$

Comment: Why is that not possible? Are you saying the population cannot decrease?

Comment: How it will be reduced by150 when there are only 100 Rats..@Arthur

Comment: @sani But that is not necessarily what that number means. It's possible for the population to reduce by the rate say 150 every second for a fraction of a second then it stops at 0 or at some number, nowhere it's implied in the equations that population should decrease by 150, it says that the rate is 150 per second or 75 per half-second or 37.5 per 0.25s .... etc Then at the next moment the rate may change to diffrent number.

Comment: at the moment $t =0$ how the population reduces by $150$  when there are only 100 Rats...@yousefmagableh

Comment: @sani  When the population of rabbits changes from 100 to 50 in 1/3 second then the rate of change of the population of rabbits will be 150 per second, that doesn't mean that the population will keep decreasing with the same rate for the whole second! The rate may change.

Comment: To better see what's going on, you can graph the function of the population P with time, and you can see what that number 150 means in the graph try at t=0 to t=0.1 to draw a tangent line, and compute the difference in the number of rabbits between the two times over the time it took to change you will get a number close to 150. That is what that number means.

Comment: I have edited the question.. Can you please check my question once again?@yousefmagableh

Comment: @sani The antiderivative of 1/x is ln(abs(x)) not ln(x). k can't be negative, but your antiderivative is missing an absolute value when you add the absolute value, it becomes clear that k>0.

Comment: how to know $\frac{1}{2}{p(t)} - 200$  is negative?@yousefmagableh

Answer (score 1):

The rate of population change dp/dt is an instantaneous rate. Let us put units on this and say that t is in days. This need not be the case but it might help visualize things. IF that is the case then we have at t=0 (on the first day) the population will start at 100 rats and decrease by 150 rats/day. You are correct, we cannot lose 150 rats. However, this rate will change, what it means in the equation is that as the day goes on, the growth rate will change. It was only -150 rats/day at the instant the day started. However, if we check the rate at say half a day forward (t=0.5) the rate becomes -91 rats/day. The rate of change can be as large or small as it wants to be, it just cannot go on for an arbitrary amount of time.